# Find a metric space in which the boundry of $M(r,p)$ is not equal to the sphere of radius $r$ at $p$

Tags: real-analysis

Find a metric space $M$ in which the boundary of $M(r,p)$ is not equal to the sphere of radius $r$ at $p$, $M(r,p)=\{x \in M: d(x,p)=r\}$
I cant understand how can the discrete space be the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$M(r,p)$ is exactly the sphere of radius $r$ at $p$. You are asked to find a space such that the boundary of the sphere is not equal to the sphere itself!

In the discrete metric every set $A$ is open and closed simultaneously. Hence, the $\partial A = \bar A \setminus \stackrel{\circ}{A} = A \setminus A = \emptyset$. This means that in the discrete metric the boundary of $M(r,p)$ is empty while the sphere itself does not have to be empty.